# Stretching a table-cell to the width of the table

Tags: css, html-table

I'm trying to stretch a table-cell to the width of my table.
The width of the table depends on the width of my last table-row.

I couldn't find a way to solve it. 
Have you got an idea or is it just impossible because of the behaviour of a table.
I created [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/S6epX/) where you can see what I mean.
My aim is to stretch the table-cell "TR1" to the width of tr3(sum of width from "TD1","TD","TD3").

This is how it should look like:

```
 ---------------
|       TR1     |
 ---------------
|       TR2     |
 ---------------
| TD1 |TD2| TD3 |
 ---------------
```

What I forgot to say is that unfortunately I cannot work with the style-attribute width 
because I'm getting data from different databases. 
I'm trying to sort them and put them into the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% on the browser restrictions of doing this, but why not put the maximum possible number of columns there could be in row 3?

Like this:

```
<tr><td colspan="20"></td>
<tr><td colspan="20"></td>
<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
```

Comment: That's exactly what I did. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Specify a colspan with the amount of cells you want the row to cover

```
<tr><td colspan="3"></td>
<tr><td colspan="3"></td>
<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
```

Comment: Colspan would be it, indeed. But what do I have to do when I do not know the numbers of table-cells from down below?

Comment: I wouldn't know about that sorry. I always just calculate the most cells I'm going to have in a row, then apply that to all the others

Answer (score 2):

The correct way of doing it is by setting colspan attribute to 100%. 
   `<table>
    <tr>
    <td colspan="100%">TR1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td colspan="100%">TR2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>TD1</td><td>TD2</td><td>TD3</td>
    </tr>
    </table>`

Comment: this is a really good answer as it doesn't depend on working out how many cells across the core data is.

Answer (score 1):

you need to span columns

```
<table style="border:3px solid black;">
<tr>
    <td class="td1" colspan="3">TR1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="td2" colspan="3">TR2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="td3">TD1</td>
    <td class="td3">TD2</td>
    <td class="td3">TD3</td>  
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Does colspan="auto" exist? I do not know the numbers of table-cells in the third table-row.